# same height images bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a responsive grid-like gallery using bootstrap but the issue is different height images.

I tried this solution but this stretches the images when being scaled and I would like to keep the aspect ratio the same. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426344/8569875]

Here is my fiddle... and code...

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  padding 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfLV8hD7zX4/maxresdefault.jpg"></li>
    <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg"></li>
    <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Mandarin.duck.arp.jpg/220px-Mandarin.duck.arp.jpg"></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: In your code, you use both `col-xs-4` and `col-xs-12`. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li{
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  padding 10px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfLV8hD7zX4/maxresdefault.jpg"></li>
    <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg"></li>
    <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Mandarin.duck.arp.jpg/220px-Mandarin.duck.arp.jpg"></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I meant to say I need them to be in a row and unfortunately this does not fix the same height problem when I run it in my jsfiddle

Comment: this works a little better thankyou. i will try to make this work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

I recommend you to set the height of the `li` tags based on the screen width using media queries, to handle screens of different sizes.

Please refer to the below link for my solution!

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**CSS:**

```
ul>li{
  height:200px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
}

img {
  padding 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  width:auto;
}
```

Comment: yes but I am trying to keep the aspect ratio of the image the same

Comment: @MichaelHands You cannot set both of them to fill the parent and also keep the aspect ratio, you can crop the image I guess, so I suggest a simpler solution, setting the height and keeping the width to auto, so that you will maintain the aspect ratio, then center the image inside the div.

Comment: Yes I'm starting to think this might be the case. I am trying to recreate something like this http://landscape-photo-pmc.premiumcoding.com/demo1/nature/

Comment: Maybe I could try to do it as background image and trim it that way :)

Comment: @MichaelHands Yes I guess so, but center the background image and crop, checkout this link [here](https://medium.com/@chrisnager/center-and-crop-images-with-a-single-line-of-css-ad140d5b4a87)