# Centering responsive images that are scaled to the same height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making all the images in my bootstrap grid the same height using an image [wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426344/2441384) and then retaining their native aspect ratios by letting their widths scale independently (see snippet below). Now I want to horizontally center them in their `div`s to make the layout tidier. I tried to use the `image-container` class below, but it hasn't worked in the various `div`s I've applied it to (currently just makes them disappear). Is there some way to horizontally center the images using the wrapper properties perhaps? I'd appreciate any helpful nudges. Thanks!

**I'm looking for a successful way to:**

- keep the images responsively scaled to the same height with different aspect ratios (as seen in the snippet below)
- horizontally center the images while retaining their responsive scaling (the point above)

See the snippet below for how the images are responsively scaled to the same height; the commented out `image-container` divs are one of my unsuccessful attempts to horizontally center the images after the scaling.

```css
    .thumbnail img{
      max-width: 100%; /* do not stretch the bootstrap column */
    }

    .img-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 130%;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .img-wrapper img {
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width:auto;
      height:100%;
    }

    .image-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <!--<div class="image-container">-->
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x300"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        <!--</div>-->
      </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <!--<div class="image-container">-->
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x350"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      <!--</div>-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <!--<div class="image-container">-->
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x300"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      <!--</div>-->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: flex` in combination with `justify-content: center` actually **does** center your images; the problem is that you have **[absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)** inside the flex:

```
.img-wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Simply removing the above code will cause your images to be centered. Note that you'll probably also want to remove `top` and `left`, as those will have no effect with the removal of `position: absolute`:

```css
.thumbnail img {
  max-width: 100%;
  /* do not stretch the bootstrap column */
}

.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 130%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  /* position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; */
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x300" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/200x350" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x300" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I took out the absolute positioning as you said, but it seems to then break the image scaling and all the images get weirdly stretched and lose their independent widths. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm. The additional height is being added from `padding-button: 130%` (which I'm not sure why you have, but I've left in), but other than that, the images seem right to me. The three images in my above example have different widths, and all I did was remove `position: absolute`. Could you please add a screenshot of the problem, or ensure you have created a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Is the way the images are showing in my answer what you're looking for? If not, could you please clarify *exactly* what needs to be different? :)

Comment: I'll work on making my code above into a snippet. In the meantime, the images in your example are different heights. The wrapper is meant to rescale the images to the same height. Taking out absolute positioning appears to break this.

Comment: The images are of differing heights because they have `height: 100%`, and variable widths. If you want your images to all be the same height, you need to give them a fixed height.

Comment: Since my site is responsive, I need to keep the same heights responsive as well. The wrapper is based on this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426344/2441384

Comment: I've added a snippet above that shows the images scaled to the same height with a wrapper, but not yet successfully centered.